# ¿Mostrar cantidad de items e input de busqueda en Datatable AdminLTE?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Laravel 5.6 e implemente [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html), todo funciona correctamente e implemente los archivos correspondientes tanto de js, css y la estructura de muestra del html.

Pero mi resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi :

```
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/plugins/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
        page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
        apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">  

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
```

Mis scripts:

```
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="/adminlte/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="/adminlte/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="/adminlte/plugins/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/adminlte/plugins/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="/adminlte/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="/adminlte/plugins/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="/adminlte/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

<!-- Optionally, you can add Slimscroll and FastClick plugins.
     Both of these plugins are recommended to enhance the
     user experience. -->
<!-- page script -->
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#posts-table').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  })
</script>
```

Estructura HTML:

```
<div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Listado de publicaciones</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="posts-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Título</th>
                  <th>Extracto</th>
                  <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->excerpt }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
```

Ya verifique las rutas y funcionan correctamente, lo que no logro es que salgan estos dos elementos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si deseas que aparezcan dichas herramientas o controles, simplemente actívalos al momento de generar la tabla, son:

- lengthChange para el filtro de cantidad de elementos
- searching para la búsqueda

Deben estar en true (es su valor predeterminado normalmente):

```
  $(function () {
    $('#posts-table').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': true,
      'searching'   : true,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  })
```

Comment: Gracias funciono correctamente, lo raro es que he usado el template en php puro y nunca me toco mover nada de eso pero bueno gracias por tu respuesta.